# How do I remove unique constraints from tables without hard coding rows?

Tags: c#, mysql, unique-constraint

I am not sure if this is a duplicate or not as there have been several how to's for removing unique constraint. I feel like my question is just different enough to warrant a new question. I have C# code which builds up mysql queries. They end out looking like this:

```
CREATE table_B like table_A;
```

I then alter each of the newly created tables to add history details similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_B 
MODIFY COLUMN primary_column int(11) NOT NULL,  
DROP KEY `PRIMARY`, 
ENGINE = MyISAM,  
ADD db_action_type VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'insert' FIRST,  
ADD revision INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER db_action_type,  
ADD dt_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER revision, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(revision);
```

Essentially, I am creating history tables. The trouble I am having is that I cannot add additional rows if the table has a unique constraint.  I could do some queries to get a list of unique constraint columns for each table and alter each column individually or as part of this alter table.  I am just wondering if there is an easy way which does not require knowing any of the column names. Is there any sort of blanket effect drop unique attribute without caring about specifics?

Comment: You can get the index information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: I used this strategy to get the primary_column in the above code. I was moreso hoping for some mysql magic.

Comment: There's a global flag that turns off all unique index checks, but nothing that can be done per-table.